# Android Activity with fixed orientation but Fragment rotates

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to have an Android `Activity` that is fixed to, say, portrait orientation but then have a fragment added to the activity that can rotate freely with device orientation changes? Is it possible to somehow do this programmatically (by calling something equiv. to `Activity.setRequestedOrientation()`)?

If this isn't possible, can there be two `Fragment`'s visible at the same time on a parent `Activity` where one `Fragment` is allowed to rotate, but the other is not?

I've searched far and wide and cannot find a solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Once you freeze the orientation, the fragment will not notice if the orientation is changed. I have used the code `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` to freeze my activity in portrait and it keeps my fragment in portrait as well. What is the use case that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Parnit I have a static background (shown in the activity) and then have a fragment that overlays it partially. When the device rotates I'd like the static background in the activity to continue to show in portrait orientation, but I want the UI in the fragment to rotate.

Comment: Hmm. The only thing I can think of is to create a landscape version of your image and place place that in the landscape folder for drawable and change to that image when you rotate. This can fulfill you need, but if the image is not symmetrical , it may slightly change based on the direction you rotate.

Comment: @Parnit thanks for the suggestions. One item in our background is actually an OpenGL view so we are hoping there is a way to fix this from rotating as well (and let any fragments rotate freely). It may be that this is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating more I've found that the architecture is simply not setup to work this way, an Activity cannot stay fixed while a hosted Fragment rotates.